# Will inspectors require a fix for pre-existing grading issues as I replace siding around an old house?

Tags: siding, sheathing, grading

I am re-siding and probably re-sheathing a portion of my house.  The house includes a carport framed in and converted to living space where the existing slab is only ~1" above grade. From what I've read a possible fix might be adding temporary supports and building a block wall to bring the "foundation wall" up 8 inches.

The house does not have proper clearance to grade on one portion (and it cannot be fixed by grading). It has been that way for ~40 years. Am I likely to be required to fix this when making modifications?

The rest of the house mostly have the 6" of clearance required by code.

Comment: We're also adding windows so there will be inspections.

Comment: Add that information to your question post, please.

Comment: Whether or not inspectors require a fix, you should endeavor to provide one!

Comment: @Huesmann do you have a suggestion for a fairly simple fix?  I'm not sure supporting ~15 feet of ceiling/roof, removing the wall, and pouring a small stem wall or laying a block one is worthwhile?  The house is 70 years old, in a dry climate, and doesn't have evidence of massive issues.

Comment: *If* the inspectors require some kind of remedial effort, grade away from the house at least 10', even if it causes a sump there; if necessary you can create an infiltration pit (assuming your soils are reasonably well-draining).  If the inspector doesn't comment, and you don't have any evidence of an issue, don't even worry about it.